# CRC32 Java Update 1st Bit

Tags: java, cryptography, crc32

I am trying to create a CRC32 of a string in java. I was able to do that with `java.util.zip.CRC32`. Now I want to update 1st bit of the crc to 0 or 1 based on some conditions. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Hava a look at the Java bitwise operations `|` and `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help for the highest bit (it is not clear which one is the first one):

```
long crc = crc32.getValue();

crc &= 0x7FFFFFFF; //sets the highest bit to 0
if (yourCondition) {
    crc |= 0x80000000; //sets the highest bit to 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitmasking to clear bit 1 first and the add in the bit you want.

```
CRC32 crc = ...;
boolean condition = ...;
int crc32 = (int) crc.getValue();
int bit = condition ? 1 : 0;
crc32 = (crc32 & ~1) | bit;
```